# createAction with 'props' or function Argument types error

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, ngrx, ngrx-store

I started refactoring my code to use the new syntax of creating actions.
For some reason, when I'm trying to create action using the attached code, the IDE (WebStorm) tells me this error:

> "Argument types do not match parameters"

Any Idea why?

I followed this article: https://medium.com/ngrx/announcing-ngrx-version-8-ngrx-data-create-functions-runtime-checks-and-mock-selectors-a44fac112627

```
export const someActionCreatedUsingFunction = createAction(
  '[Actions] SOME_ACTION',
  (payload: any) => ({payload})
);

export const someActionCreatedUsingProps = createAction(
  '[Actions] SOME_ACTION',
  props<{payload: any}>()
);
```

Comment: Just try your code with my vs code and it dont have any problem

Comment: are you importing `creationAction` and `props` from `@ngrx/store` ?

Comment: Yes, both are imported from @ngrx/store

Comment: This seems fine to me, can you reproduce this in stackblitz/github repo?
Make sure you've also updated the angular version to v8.x